# Use of a class from a second target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

As the `IBDesignable` attribute needs the designable class to be in a seperate target I created a second target which worked great in the designer. When I then tried to use the new class in my code I get the error

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'CustomMarker'"

I have imported the second target in my main target -- `import CustomViews` --  and I can cmd+click the target name to see the main .h file that describes the target; where the class is included. The compiler still can't find the class in my code though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Fixed this by changing access modifier of the class to ***public***.

```
@IBDesignable public class MyCustomView: UIView {

}
```

By default classes and methods will be at `internal` access level. If you want to use that out side of the target, you should mark it as `public`. Then only it will be the part of public interface(visible to outside of target)

Comment: Thank you. I saw that public vs private was introduced in Swift recently but I hadn't given it a second thought

Answer (score 0):

second target must be of type "framework". 
you must also link it in build phases like as an external framework. link binary with libraries must have a link to your customViews framework and embed framework must have that link too.

that should be enough.